# trim all special characters at start and end of a sql database value

Tags: sql-server, string, vb.net, sql-update

```sql
Update [asset_loc] 
Set [column name] ='<after trimming all special characters in field  ** trim from start and trim from end>'
where <column name> like '<pick values that start or end with spl characters
```

[image]

Sample data:

- `, ,/ a/22/,,,`
- `a/22../`
- `/.,, a/22`

Desired result after query execution:

```
a/22
```

Comment: Post sample data as textual form, not as image. Post an attempted query. Run `SELECT Version();` to check exact MySQL version.

Comment: It looks fiddly enough that a regular expression would be needed: [How to do a regular expression replace in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/986826/how-to-do-a-regular-expression-replace-in-mysql)

Comment: Are you trying to get the result through MySQL query? Because I can see you've updated your sample data but you didn't post any attempted query. Makes me think that you're trying achieve this through a different method? In fact, are you actually using MySQL database or sql-server?

Comment: Firstly Iam using SQL Server databases where more than 470 databases are in a single instance and trying to acheive through sql query. If that is not possible then please suggest some alternative. Using vb.net as front end

Comment: @RajeshSubramanya If you are using Microsoft SQL Server (which the tags on your question say you are *not* but your comment says you are), then you can use the [TRIM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/trim-transact-sql) function: `UPDATE [tableName] SET [colName] = TRIM('.,/? ' FROM [colName])`.

Comment: Can you remove the mysql tag to avoid confusion?

Comment: Thanks. UPDATE [tableName] SET [colName] = TRIM('.,/? ' FROM [colName] has worked and task accomplished.